# Role authorization in .net core 2.0 using Identity

Tags: authorization, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.0

I am using .net core 2.0 and trying to do authorization using asp identity in a mvc website.
(Authentication is done using Google OAuth).

Authentication is working fine i.e users can access controllers/views after logging in through google. But when I try adding a role("Admin") to a particular controller, I get unauthorized.

Setup reference : https://github.com/TahirNaushad/Fiver.Security.AspIdentity/
DB : MySql

Below is my startup configuration:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<AppIdentityDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseMySql(configuration["DB_CONN"]));

        services.AddIdentity<AppIdentityUser, AppIdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppIdentityDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddAuthentication().AddGoogle(googleOptions =>
        {
            googleOptions.ClientId = "******.apps.googleusercontent.com";
            googleOptions.ClientSecret = "******";
            googleOptions.SaveTokens = true;
            googleOptions.AccessType = "offline";
        });

        services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-._@+ ";

            options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;
            options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
            options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 5;

            options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
        });

        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
        {
            options.LoginPath = "/Security/Login";
            options.LogoutPath = "";
            options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Security/AccessDenied";
            options.SlidingExpiration = true;
            options.Cookie = new CookieBuilder
            {
                HttpOnly = true,
                Name = ".Test",
                Path = "/",
                SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax,
                SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest
            };
        });
        services.AddMvc();
    }

    public void Configure(
        IApplicationBuilder app,
        IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
    }
```

Authorization using role:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;  
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace Test.Controllers
{
    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
    public class MoviesController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Note: 1. Entries are present in AspNetUsers, AspNetRoles and AspNetUserRoles
2. I checked online and found that roles should be present in Principal.Claims with claim type as roles but for me that is not true.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that there was no problem in configuration. While signing in a user using its username, I had created a new User object to sign in.
What I was supposed to do is - use the username to fetch User object from DB and use that object to sign in.

Hope this helps someone who stumbles upon similar problem.